# Проблема с высотой родителя в CSS column layout

Tags: css

У меня высота родителя меняется в зависимости от вложенного в дочерний элемент блока с absolute.

Мне нужно чтобы высота была фиксированной и не зависела от скрытого блока.

Вот мой пример кода:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 3%;
  column-width: 30%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: #fff;
}

.child {
  padding: 20px;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  background-color: rgb(255, 193, 26);
  position: relative
}

.child:hover .hidden {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 60px 20px 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 193, 26);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="title">
      Заголовок элемента
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      За 6 лет более 1 000 клиентов обратились к нам для проведения работы в квартирах, офисах, магазинах, гостиницах, производствах.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблемы из-за использования `column-count, column-gap, column-width` - вот с использованием flexbox и все работает как Вы задумывали:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: #fff;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 193, 26);
  
  position: relative;
}

.child:hover .hidden {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 60px 20px 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 193, 26);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="title">
      Заголовок элемента
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      За 6 лет более 1 000 клиентов обратились к нам для проведения работы в квартирах, офисах, магазинах, гостиницах, производствах.
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    <div class="title">
      Заголовок элемента
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      За 6 лет более 1 000 клиентов обратились к нам для проведения работы в квартирах, офисах, магазинах, гостиницах, производствах.
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    <div class="title">
      Заголовок элемента
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      За 6 лет более 1 000 клиентов обратились к нам для проведения работы в квартирах, офисах, магазинах, гостиницах, производствах.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А сетку masonry через flex не сделать, не указывая высоту родителя. Мне нужно использовать именно column layout.

Comment: С `column layout` боюсь у Вас не получится сделать, даже если что-то выдумывать, то все-равно будет переносится на следующую колонку. К тому же `column-count` - должны применяться к display:inline-block, а `column-width` вообще плохо поддерживается браузерами. В общем извиняйте тогда, не смог помочь.